# How to Restore Form Field Values from Dictionary Keys

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to allow a user to redirect from a page that collects user input. Should the user redirect, upon return to the page the form should be filled in with the values that the user had already entered.

I completed the following but I'm guessing there is a better way to do this.

```
On RedirectEvent()
{
    Dictionary<string, string> form = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (string key in Request.Form.AllKeys)
    {
        if (key != null)
        form.Add(key, Request.Form[key]);
    }
    Session["requestFormKeys"] = form;

    Response.Redirect(url);
}


On Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Session["requestFormKeys"] != null)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> form = Session["requestFormKeys"] as   Dictionary<string, string>;
        // I tried using 'Request.Form.AllKeys' here but it was always null
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string>pair in form)
        {
            // cannot use a switch because switch requires a constant (value must be known at compile time)
            if (pair.Key.Contains("txtName"))
                    txtName.Text = lblNameView.Text = pair.Value;
            else if (pair.Key.Contains("ddlType"))
                    ddlType.SelectedValue = pair.Value;
            else if (pair.Key.Contains("ddlPriority"))
                    ddlPriority.SelectedValue = pair.Value;
                              .
                              .
                              .         
            //this is a tedious process and should be streamlined
                              .
                              .
                              .
            else if (pair.Key.Contains("txtDateStart"))
                    txtDateStart.Text = pair.Value;
            else if (pair.Key.Contains("txtDateEnd"))
                    txtDateEnd.Text = pair.Value;

        }
   }
   Session.Remove("requestFormKeys");
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: KeyValuePair within the Dictionary would work but my question is how are you saving the State of the Dictionary.. could you perhaps look at using Session objects and investigating the Session.Add method.. just and Idea.. or Cookies..? you could look into Hidden Fields, or ViewState as long as you are not saving large amouts of text / data. which I personally would not use if I don't have to.. There are Global.asax sections where you could also use / store Session vars.. when dealing with Web I generally go with using Session variables.. but thats just my personal choice..

Comment: When you say 'how are you saving the State of the Dictionary', are you asking how I am saving the dictionary? If so, I am saving it to Session in the OnRedirectEvent() method

Comment: I meant are you passing that Dictionary by ref because on postback that object should be null but personally I would go with Session or Cookies Alans example should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming a database is out of the question because we are dealing with an anonymous user - putting the dictionary in the Session could be a little heavy on server resources - unless you  run a separate stateserver or sqlserver for the session.

Persisting the values in a client side cookie collection would work for an anonymous user - though increase bytes over the wire.

```
Response.Cookies["mypage"]["textbox1"] = textbox1.Text;
Response.Cookies["mypage"]["textbox2"] = textbox2.Text;
```

Remember to HTML encode the cookie in case the cookie has been hacked with client-side script on the way back

```
if (Request.Cookies["mypage"] != null)
textbox1.Text = Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["mypage"]["textbox1"].Value);
```

Comment: That is a good idea, but what I am mainly after is, is there a way to avoid manually filling the values for each of the fields. That is, something like iterating all the fields in the form and setting their values from the dictionary (or cookie). I tried Request.Form.AllKeys but it was always null in Page_Load upon returning to the form

Comment: can you not iterate the controls collection - going out and coming back in - though you'll have to cast from Control to a specific Control type to pull/set the values.

Comment: I ended up iterating through the controls as @Alan suggested. Thanks for all the feedback. I had to 'drill down' into HtmlDataTable > HtmlDataRow > HtmlDataCell to get at the controls I needed (drilled down means nested foreach loops)